# What's the best way to handle massively over-promising on a research project?

Tags: masters, computer-science

I am complete a CS research project as part of my program requirements. From the summary description of the project it seemed to tick all the areas I have expertise in such as database, storage, and systems programming.

I greatly underestimated the complexity of the project. And even though my expertise help me plan a roadmap and a high-level understanding, at the implementation level I am massively struggling with the details. The project uses a language I'm not that familiar with and even a unique build system.

I've severely overestimated my ability here and given several reports to professors of timelines to collect data and implement features that now I realize I'm way out of my depth for.

**What is the best course of action to not destroy my relationship with the faculty and research leads?**

Comment: Is there a supervisor? Have you talked with them?

Answer (score 5):

Communicate early and often.

You're new to research. You need mentors at this stage in your career (really most everyone does at every stage, but later on you can call them "peers" you ask for advice). Research mentors are particularly useful for setting the scope of projects. If you're in over your head, either your mentors have failed to caution you or they've chosen to let you dive right in and see what you're capable of and let you learn from the experience of biting off too much.

Share with them your struggles and any new estimates you have on an appropriate scope. Ask for their advice on how to proceed - that's what they're there for. If they berate you or let your relationship deteriorate over this, then they weren't any good as mentors from the get go and you haven't lost much by losing that relationship. Good mentors will help you through.

The thing you don't want to do is to lie about your progress, or wait until the last minute. If you're early in the project, there is lots of time left to revamp your goals. If you wait until the project is due, there is little you can do but state what you've tried and failed to accomplish.

Comment: In real research at the cutting edge, _any_ promise of success, or even progress, is over-promising. The unknown is unknown.

Comment: @Buffy Sure, though it depends on your field a bit. A well-designed experiment should give a good result (though the direction can't be guaranteed or else it wasn't a useful experiment) and can be done in a predictable amount of time. OP's issue doesn't seem to be that the answer to their research question turned out to be uninteresting or that all the avenues they pursued failed to solve a given problem, but rather that implementing their proposed solution has come to be too much work for the project scope.

Comment: @Buffy while the research isn't completely new globally, the only prior works I have seen of someone completing this were two full-time engineering teams at Alibaba and Tencent. I wasn't aware at that prior hand and thought there would be plenty of documentation for me to build off of. It is pretty much nonexistent.

Comment: @ADS well that's the point of learning, isn't it? Get as much experience as you can while you're a student and don't have the responsibility to see multimillion contracts to fruition. If it's of any consolation, with over a decade of experience in the field I sometimes still massively miss the mark with these pesky estimates, and the only difference is that the entire project does not depend on it. Since you're in CS, [I highly recommend reading some Joel's thoughts on management](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2007/10/26/evidence-based-scheduling/). And then re-read it every 5 years or so.

Comment: +1. I'll just add that it's quite likely the professors know you underestimated how difficult this would be, and will be pleased to see that you figured this out on your own and are dealing with it proactively.